# Adding floats, integers and to pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I'm very new to programming and I have been trying to do the following, but I don't know if I am doing it right.

I have the following declarations

```
int a, b, c;
int *p1, *p2, *p3;
char d, str[10], *cp;
float big, r;
```

and with those declarations I have to find out how to declare the following q variables.
For example, if *p3 is a integer pointer and r is a float. then what would q1 would have to be. I need to find out how to declare it.

But since each one is of a different type, I don't know how to do it. Some hints would be kindly appreciated

```
q1 = r + *p3;                     
q2 = &p1 + 5;
q3 = *str + c;
q4 = &str[4];
q5 = *p2;
```

Comment: Why aren't there any q's in your code?  What are they?

Comment: I've added the "c" tag to your question, assuming that that's the language you're using. If that's incorrect (say, if you're using C++), please update it.

Comment: Are you asking for the types of the q variables?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you need to declare `q1` et al so that the five assignment statements are valid? (Note that `q2 = &p1 + 5;` will be *legal* if `q2` is of type `int**`, but its behavior would still be undefined.)

Comment: Yes, I'm asking for the types of the q variables

Comment: @user2793064: There's no unique answer. `r` is a `float`, and `*p3` is an `int`; their sum could be assigned to an object of any numeric type.

Answer (score 3):

```
int a, b, c;
int *p1, *p2, *p3;
char d, str[10], *cp;
float big, r;
```

So I think the question is to use the declarations above, and the expressions below and come up with a valid set of types for the expressions.

```
q1 = r + *p3;           
q2 = &p1 + 5; 
q3 = *str + c;  
q4 = &str[4];  
q5 = *p2;
```

I think these types are valid for the expressions above:

```
float q1 = r + *p3;  // float = float + int                   
int **q2 = &p1 + 5;  // int ** = int** + int
int q3 = *str + c;   // int = char + int
char *q4 = &str[4];  // char * = char *
int q5 = *p2;        // int = *int*
```

q1, q3 and q5 could be any numeric type. I picked the one most obvious to me.

Comment: q2 should not be an int, since pointer is unsigned. Possibly either unsigned int or 64 bit unsigned.

Comment: @AviPerel I respectfully disagree. p1 is a pointer to an int. &p1 is a pointer to a pointer to an int. &p1 + 5 is a pointer to a pointer to an int. The fact that pointers are unsigned have nothing to do with what they point to.

Comment: you are of course correct. Bad phrasing on my behalf, What I meant to say is that a pointer is not a signed value, regardless of what it points to.